# Extension host terminated unexpectedly in VS Code on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code for almost 2 months, it was working great. after i installed some extensions and reloaded them, it gives me this error *Extension host terminated unexpectedly*. i have searched about it and found some solutions but it is not working.

1. removed git folder
2. uninstalled all extensions
3. disabled the git in settings.json file
4. removed cached files of the software
5. even uninstalled VS code and installed again, but it gives me the same error that says:

"Extension host terminated unexpectedly"

Comment: Just for testing purposes...can you start vscode with the `--disable-extensions` parameter, and check if it works as expected

Comment: same message :( 
command: Code.exe --disable-extensions

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95036#issuecomment-612573284

Open QuickHeal->Tools->View Quarantine Files->restore the respective files

Comment: This question is from two years ago.  Is it the same problem?